# Manually deleting unused Images on kubernetes (GKE)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a managed kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform with a single node for development.

However when I update Pod images too frequently, the ImagePull step fails due to insufficient disk space in the boot disk.

I noticed that images should be auto GC-ed according to documentation, but I have no idea what is the setting on GKE or how to change it.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/#image-collection

1. Can I manually trigger a unused image clean up, using `kubectl` or Google Cloud console command?
2. How do I check/change the above GC setting above such that I wont encounter this issue in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Garbage Collector is an automated service, there are no kubectl commands or any other commands within GCP to manually trigger Garbage Collector.

In regards to your second inquiry, Garbage Collector is handled by the Master node. The Master node is not accessible to users since it is a managed service. As such, users cannot configure Garbage Collection withing GKE.

The only workaround I can offer is to [create a custom cluster from scratch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/scratch/) within Google Compute Engine. This would provide you access to the Master node of your cluster so you can have the flexibility of configuring the cluster to your liking.

Edit: If you need to delete old images, I would suggest removing the old images using docker commands. I have attached a github article that provides several different commands that you can run on the node level to remove old images [here](https://gist.github.com/bastman/5b57ddb3c11942094f8d0a97d461b430).

Comment: That makes sense, but does that mean every time I encounter the disk size problem, the only solution is to completely delete the node boot disk?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Look at the section of my answer that starts with "Edit"